# nError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index

Tags: python

I keep getting this error and i dont know what I did wrong? Hopefully somebody can help me. My code is:

```
def bmsim_vec(T, N, X0, mu, sigma, numsim):
    np.random.seed(0)
    deltaT = float(T)/N
    tvec = np.linspace(0, T, N+1)
    z = np.random.randn(numsim, N+1)
    dX = mu*deltaT + sigma*np.sqrt(deltaT)*z
    dX[:, 0] = 0.
    X = np.cumsum(dX, axis=1)
    X += X0
    return tvec, X

def certificate(S0, T, R, sigma, delta, numsim=3):
    N = T
    r = np.log(1+R)
    X0 = np.log(S0)
    nu = (r-delta)-0.5*sigma**2
    _, X = bmsim_vec(T, N, X0, nu, sigma, numsim)
    S = np.exp(X)
    pay = np.zeros_like(S)
    payoffs = np.zeros(numsim)
    for i in xrange(numsim):
        for j in xrange(1, T+1):
            pay[i, j] = np.maximum((1+(S[i, j]-S[i, j-1])/S[i, j-1]), (1+R))
            payoffs[i] = pay[i,1:].mean()
    g = np.exp(-r*T)*(payoffs)**T*S0
    C = g.mean(); s = g.std()
    zq = norm.ppf(0.975)
    Cl = C - zq/np.sqrt(numsim)*s
    Cu = C + zq/np.sqrt(numsim)*s
    return C, Cl, Cu
```

My values are:

```
S0=11.;T=10.;R=0.02;sigma=0.3;delta=.01
certificate(S0, T, R, sigma, delta, numsim=3)
```

The error I keep getting is this one:

```
<ipython-input-28-0d5bc37c7944> in <module>()
      1 S0=11.;T=10.;R=0.02;sigma=0.3;delta=.01
----> 2 certificate(S0, T, R, sigma, delta, numsim=3)

<ipython-input-27-63ec11c0d8b5> in certificate(S0, T, R, sigma, delta, numsim)
      4     X0 = np.log(S0)
      5     nu = (r-delta)-0.5*sigma**2
----> 6     _, X = bmsim_vec(T, N, X0, nu, sigma, numsim)
      7     S = np.exp(X)
      8     pay = np.zeros_like(S)

<ipython-input-22-3a607f23c728> in bmsim_vec(T, N, X0, mu, sigma, numsim)
      3     deltaT = float(T)/N
      4     tvec = np.linspace(0, T, N+1)
----> 5     z = np.random.randn(numsim, N+1)
      6     dX = mu*deltaT + sigma*np.sqrt(deltaT)*z
      7     dX[:, 0] = 0.

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.randn()

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.standard_normal()

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.cont0_array()
```

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an index

Hopefully someone sees my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to include which language you are writing in. Just saying this question is about [tag:indexing] is not enough.

Comment: Post full error traceback

Comment: does changing `T=10.` to `T=10` solve your problem?  If so, that's the float that should be an int. (or change `N=T` to `N=int(T)`)